# How to add space in textbox until max length reached?

Tags: winforms

i want to add a space (      ) in text box until the maximum length reached (1000)

and i want to write text in the textbox concat the space so the text is first and after the text finished the space start until max length of textbox reached for example.

**like below :**

```
textbox1.text = "mytext" + "                   ";
```

but i want the space just to fill the textbox until max length (1000) reached.

and the other thing  i want is if the text in the textbox is bigger than the max length
then remove the excess (the text after 1000)

please help

Comment: You don't want much do you

Comment: String.Len does miracles.

Comment: Trailing spaces are usually a pain.  Why do you want to add potentially hundreds of spaces to the end of a string?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: @KSdev: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [string.PadRight()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.PadRight(textbox1.MaxLength, ' ');
```

Comment: You've not actually specified which sort of textbox we're talking about web/winforms/wpf but this should work regardless (assuming MaxLength is there)

Answer (score 1):

First check if the length is greater than the maximum permitted, if it is then use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cut it down to size. If the length is less than max, then you can use [`PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pad the text...

```
string text = textbox1.Text;//get the text to manipulate
int max = 1000;

if(text.Length > max)//If the current text length is greater than max
    text = text.Substring(0, max);//trim the text to the maximum allowed
else
    text = text.PadRight(max, ' ');//pad extra spaces up until the correct length

//text will now be the same length as max (with spaces if required)

textbox1.Text = text;//set the new text value back to the TextBox
```

---

**NOTE**: Because you have asked about trimming the text to the maximum length, then I have assumed you have not used the [`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `TextBox` - as this would already prevent adding more than the limit, I would recommend using that instead then you don't have to worry about trimming yourself, you could then just do:

```
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.PadRight(textbox1.MaxLength, ' ');
```

Comment: BUT AFTER I ADD THIS CODE TO A BUTTON NOTHING HAPPENS IT DOESNT TRIM OR ADDING SPACE

Comment: can you give me the source of the project please

Comment: @user3227682: It is above, in my answer. I just put that in a button click event like you said you tried. I can't give you full project source. You are using the top bit of code right? Are you using WinForms?

Comment: i use c# what is winforms

Comment: @user3227682: WinForms = Windows Forms Application, the type of app you are building. Other options include WPF and ASP.Net WebForms

Comment: HI THANK YOU MAN THE CODE WORK BUT BEFORE I DON'T COPY THE LAST LINE FROM THE CODE THANK YOU. YOU HELP ME A LOT BUT I CAN'T RATE YOU BECAUSE I AM NEW USER.

Comment: @user3227682: You can accept my answer though if it solved your problem, just click the green tick

Answer (score 0):

I think that's all you wanted right?

```
public String writeMax(String myText, int maxLenght)
{
  int count = myText.Length;
  String temp = "";

  if(count >= maxLength)
  {
    temp = myText.substring(0, maxLength);
  }
  else
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < maxLength - count; i++)
    {
      temp += " ";
    }
    temp = myText + temp;
  }
  return temp;
}
```